# I'm trying to write a simple password validation system for my class but it won't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not really sure why it's not working properly. But I'm thinking it's a mistake or a bug on my part.
I'm open to any help whatsoever as I have no experience with debugging anything this complicated.

```html
<html>
  </head><title> Lesson14</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function xPass(){
    alert("Invalid Password");
    }
    function cPass[]{
    alert("Welcome! You have entered the correct password.")-
    } -->
    (/script)
    </head>
  
  <body>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  <!=var password=prompt("Enter the password");
   if(password!=null)
     { var pass=password;
     if (pass=="123456"){
     cPass()
     }
      while(
       xPass();
      }
   }
  --}
  </script>
 <body>
</html>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--var password=prompt("Enter the password");
        if (password != null) {
            var pass = password;
            if (pass == "123456") {
                cPass();
            } else {
                xPass();
            }
        }
        -->
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML and JS is invalid. What is the deal with --}  and `<!=var password=prompt(`

Comment: There is actually not much correct in the JS. It is nearly impossible to guess what you actually want to do.

Comment: `(/script)`  should be `</script>` for example

Comment: Would you be willing to explain more in detail. Sorry again I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Please remove all `<!--` and `-->`

Comment: The first `</head>` should be `<head>`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain my mistakes. I appreciate the help immensely.

Comment: Sorry that you had to take the time to help me.

Comment: I have no excuses. It's my fault entirely.

Comment: We all had to start somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please study this

I cleaned up your HTML and scripts

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Lesson14</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function xPass() {
      alert("Invalid Password");
    }

    function cPass() {
      alert("Welcome! You have entered the correct password.");
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var password = prompt("Enter the password");
    if (password != null) {
      if (password == "123456") {
        cPass()
      } else {
        xPass()
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But you can also have all the script in the head and run on load of the page

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Lesson14</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function xPass() {
      alert("Invalid Password");
    }

    function cPass() {
      alert("Welcome! You have entered the correct password.");
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      var password = prompt("Enter the password");
      if (password != null) {
        if (password == "123456") {
          cPass();
        } else {
          xPass();
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  Welcome
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Few of your codes are invalid as commented and few are not correct.

1. `<!-- !>` Stands for commenting
2. `cPass[]` square brackets in function does not works.
3. You can use a single script.
4. `var pass=password;` no need to assign to new variable password
   itself works fine.
5. `while` does not make sense here `else` works fine.

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function xPass(){
       alert("Invalid Password");
       }
       function cPass(){
        alert("Welcome! You have entered the correct password.");
       } 

     var password=prompt("Enter the password");

     if(password!=null){            { 
       if(password=="123456"){
         cPass();
       }
       else{
         xPass();
       }
    }
   ```

Comment: Above is just to clear your code at once will help you. For validation check this out https://www.javatpoint.com/confirm-password-validation-in-javascript will help you.